# Two stroke engine stalls during incle

Tags: gasoline, stall, two-stroke, harley-davidson

Sir I have 1967 two stroke Harley Davidson golf cart. It runs great on level ground but when I try to go up a incline hill it wants to stall and it only makes it up the hill using the choke. I changed the fuel filter but no help. Any suggestions greatly appreciated. I am a novice when it comes to mechanics

Comment: Have you changed the air filter? Have you done any other servicing or had it serviced by anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a problem with the carburetor float chamber.
The float may not be keeping a sufficient supply of fuel in the reservoir.
You could try opening the float chamber and checking the float for leaks and also check the valve mechanism.